# C - How can I print random word inside game board (2d array)?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, function-pointers

I am writing a typing game using the C language and the Cygwin Terminal.

I have read from a .txt file 1000 words, then I printed a random word. I need to print this random word inside a 2d array box "gameboard"

[Link to: Image of current output. Need to move word from outside of box to inside of box.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CWqM.png)

**How can I print my random word inside the box?**

The word needs to show up on the top row of the box at a random horizontal location.

Note: when I say box, I mean a 20 (height) by 80 (width) box made of dashes and asterisks.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>

void main(){

    int g, h; //index for use in for loop

        //creates box
    const int boxLength = 20;
    const int boxWidth = 75;
    char box[boxLength][boxWidth];
    for(int g = 0; g < boxLength; g++){
        for(int h = 0; h < boxWidth; h++){
            if(g == 0 || g == boxLength - 1)
                box[g][h] = '-';
            else if(h == 0 || h == boxWidth - 1)
                box[g][h] = '|';
            else
                box[g][h] = ' ';
            }
    }       

            FILE *myFilePointer2 = fopen("wordList.txt", "r");

            srand(time(0));
            int size = 1000;

            if(myFilePointer2 == NULL){
                printf("Unable to open file wordList.txt");
                exit(0);
            }

            char** words = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char**)*size); //2d pointer array, dynamically allocated, to store words from text file

            char wordBankArray[1050];//wordBankArray

            int wordQuantity = 0;

            while(fgets(wordBankArray, 1050, myFilePointer2) != NULL){// read data from myFilePointer line by line and store it into words array
                words[wordQuantity] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(wordBankArray)+1)); //dynamically allocates memory for words array
                strcpy(words[wordQuantity], wordBankArray); //copying words from text file to wordBankArray
                wordQuantity++;
            }

            printf("Randomly generated word from .txt file: ");
            int index = rand()%wordQuantity;   // psuedo randomly generates an index in range of 0 to wordQuantity)

            printf("%s\n", words[index]); //prints randomly generated word from index

            for(int g = 0; g < boxLength; g++){ //prints 2d box
                for(int h = 0; h < boxWidth; h++){
                    printf("%c", box[g][h]);
                }
                printf("\n");
                fclose(myFilePointer2); //close file for reading
            }
    }
```

Comment: You said you are able to "Print a random word from the text file". How does that relate to not being able to "print my random word inside the box"? It's not clear what part you don't know how do do because "having trouble" is not very precise.

Comment: And please attempt to provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That is, remove all the code that doesn't relate to the core issue. Or create a new minimal example which demonstrates what particular concept you are having trouble with.

Comment: Hello and thank you for replying to my post. I will revise the code to a minimum and revise my question be very specific. Thank you for the tips.

Comment: Just print the word as part of printing the box. That is, you can't easily print the box and then insert the word later (well, you can but need to use a terminal library like `ncurses`).

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "print the word as part of printing the box?" I was told ncurses was off limits for this project. Thank you @kaylum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

Get the array of words and select a random word like you're already doing in your code. Here, I'm assuming the random word to be 'randomWord'.
Then get the random word position by using the rand() function, as shown in the code below.

```
char randomWord[20]="Program";
int wordLen = strlen(randomWord);
srand(time(0));
//Generates the random position of the word
//Subtract '2' because of the borders of the box and the word length so it can fit in the box
int wordPos = rand() % (boxWidth-wordLen-2);

for(int g = 0; g < boxLength; g++){
    for(int h = 0; h < boxWidth; h++){
        if(g == 1 && h == wordPos){ //Inserts the word at the top and at the random position
            for(int i = 0; i < wordLen; i++){
                box[g][h] = randomWord[i];
                h++;
            }
            box[g][h] = ' ';
        }
        if(g == 0 || g == boxLength - 1)
            box[g][h] = '-';
        else if(h == 0 || h == boxWidth - 1)
            box[g][h] = '|';
        else
            box[g][h] = ' ';
    }
}
```

Then simply print the box like you're already doing.
You should see something like this:
[Result of the box with the random word inside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUtQ8.png)

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thank you very much leticiabma for the helpful information. I ended up incorporating a similar idea in my code using strLen. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of small errors, and if you are reading a file with 1000 words but only allocating 100 pointers -- you invoke undefined behavior attempting to write to pointers that do not exist.

You don't need `fclose()` inside your `for(int g = 0; g < boxLength; g++){` loop (that closes the file `boxlength` number of times).

If you are defining `const int ...` then you are creating a 2D VLA (variable length array), which is fine, but if the bounds are known before compile time, declare constants with `#define` instead and avoid the VLA which does not exist in C89/90, was introduced in C99 and became an optional feature in C11.

You should also add `-Wshadow` to your compile string, you shadow the variables:

```
int g, h; //index for use in for loop
```

When you declare the loop variables:

```
for(int g = 0; g < boxLength; g++){
    for(int h = 0; h < boxWidth; h++){
    ...
```

(be careful with your variable declarations -- here you don't later use `g` or `h`, but in other circumstances shadowed variables can have dire consequences)

With that in mind you can define the needed constants as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>

#define BXLEN   20      /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define BXWDT   75
#define WRDSZ  100
#define ARRSZ 1050
```

(you can choose whatever names you like)

Unless you are working in a *freestanding environment* (without an operating system), your declaration of `void main()` is wrong. In a standards conforming implementation, the allowable declarations for `main` for are `int main (void)` and `int main (int argc, char *argv[])` (which you will see written with the equivalent `char **argv`).  See: [C11 Standard - §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup(p1)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p1).

The arguments `int argc, and char **argv` allow you to pass information into your program on the command line. Don't hardcode filenames. (if you are on an embedded system -- that is an exception as you may have no way to pass a filename on the command line) Otherwise, you can do:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    int nptrs = WRDSZ, index, wordQuantity = 0;     /* declare/initialize vars */
    char box[BXLEN][BXWDT] =  {{0}},
        **words = NULL,
        wordBankArray[ARRSZ] = "";
    FILE *fp = NULL;

    if (argc < 2 ) {    /* validate 1 argument given for filename */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input,\n"
                         "usage: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    /* open file/validate file open for reading */
    if ((fp = fopen (argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
        perror ("fopen-argv[1]");
        return 1;
    }
```

(**note:** I shortened `myFilePointer2` to `fp`)

When you dynamically allocate memory with `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc` in C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714). If you use the dereferenced pointer to set your typesize -- you will never get it wrong. You can allocate pointers for `words` with:

```
    if (!(words = malloc (nptrs * sizeof *words))) {    /* allocate/validate */
        perror ("malloc-words");
        return 1;
    }
```

(**note:** you must validate every allocation)

Note above, you only allocate an initial `WRDSZ` (`100`) pointers. If your file has 1000-words, you must keep track of the number of pointers filled, (your `wordQuantity`) and you must track the number of pointers allocated (say with `nptrs`). When `wordQuantity == nptrs` you must `realloc` the number of pointers available through `words` before you attempt to use another pointer (generally doubling the current number allocated is a reasonable growth scheme). Adding the additional test and reallocation, your read loop would become:

```
    while (fgets (wordBankArray, ARRSZ, fp) != NULL) {  /* read each line in file */
        size_t len;     /* save length, then memcpy */
        if (wordQuantity == nptrs) {    /* check if all pointers used - realloc */
            /* always realloc using a temporary pointer -- not the pointer itself */
            void *tmp = realloc (words, 2 * nptrs * sizeof *words);
            if (!tmp) {     /* validate realloc succeeds */
                perror ("realloc-words");
                break;      /* don't exit, original words pointer still valid */
            }
            words = tmp;    /* assign reallocated block to original pointer */
            nptrs *= 2;     /* update number of pointers allocated */
        }
        if (!(words[wordQuantity] = malloc ((len = strlen (wordBankArray)) + 1))) {
            perror ("malloc-words[wordQuantity]");
            return 1;
        }
        memcpy (words[wordQuantity], wordBankArray, len + 1);
        wordQuantity++;
    }
    fclose (fp);
```

(**note:** you only need to call `strlen()` once, saving the size and then copy the string with `memcpy()`. If you call `strcpy()`, you are just scanning again for the end of string which you already have from your call to `strlen()`)

After you are done reading, then call `fclose()` at that point. Also note `sizeof (char)` is `1` and should be omitted from your size multiplications. The remainder of what you have will print the box and output a random string, but note where there is no conversion in the output required, there is no need to call `printf`. `puts` or `fputs` will do (a good compiler will make that change for you behind the scenes)

What you miss is freeing the memory you have allocated. For that you can do:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < wordQuantity; i++)      /* free allocated strings */
        free (words[i]);
    free (words);                               /* free pointers */
```

If you put that altogether, you can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>

#define BXLEN   20      /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define BXWDT   75
#define WRDSZ  100
#define ARRSZ 1050

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    int nptrs = WRDSZ, index, wordQuantity = 0;     /* declare/initialize vars */
    char box[BXLEN][BXWDT] =  {{0}},
        **words = NULL,
        wordBankArray[ARRSZ] = "";
    FILE *fp = NULL;

    if (argc < 2 ) {    /* validate 1 argument given for filename */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input,\n"
                         "usage: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    for (int g = 0; g < BXLEN; g++) {                   /* initialize box */
        for (int h = 0; h < BXWDT; h++) {
            if (g == 0 || g == BXLEN - 1)
                box[g][h] = '-';
            else if (h == 0 || h == BXWDT - 1)
                box[g][h] = '|';
            else
                box[g][h] = ' ';
        }
    }

    /* open file/validate file open for reading */
    if ((fp = fopen (argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
        perror ("fopen-argv[1]");
        return 1;
    }

    srand (time (NULL));                                /* seed rand generator */

    if (!(words = malloc (nptrs * sizeof *words))) {    /* allocate/validate */
        perror ("malloc-words");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets (wordBankArray, ARRSZ, fp) != NULL) {  /* read each line in file */
        size_t len;     /* save length, then memcpy */
        if (wordQuantity == nptrs) {    /* check if all pointers used - realloc */
            /* always realloc using a temporary pointer -- not the pointer itself */
            void *tmp = realloc (words, 2 * nptrs * sizeof *words);
            if (!tmp) {     /* validate realloc succeeds */
                perror ("realloc-words");
                break;      /* don't exit, original words pointer still valid */
            }
            words = tmp;    /* assign reallocated block to original pointer */
            nptrs *= 2;     /* update number of pointers allocated */
        }
        if (!(words[wordQuantity] = malloc ((len = strlen (wordBankArray)) + 1))) {
            perror ("malloc-words[wordQuantity]");
            return 1;
        }
        memcpy (words[wordQuantity], wordBankArray, len + 1);
        wordQuantity++;
    }
    fclose (fp);

    fputs ("Randomly generated string from list : ", stdout);
    index = rand() % wordQuantity;
    printf ("%s\n", words[index]);

    for (int g = 0; g < BXLEN; g++) {
        for (int h = 0; h < BXWDT; h++) {
            printf ("%c", box[g][h]);
        }
        putchar ('\n');
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < wordQuantity; i++)      /* free allocated strings */
        free (words[i]);
    free (words);                               /* free pointers */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

For the data file `dat/1kfnames.txt`, I simply redirected 1000 filenames to the file to serve as words:

```
$ ./bin/wordinbox dat/1kfnames.txt
Randomly generated string from list : str_printf_null.c

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                                                         |
|                                                                         |
|                                                                         |
|                                                                         |
|                                                                         |
|                                                                         |
|                                                                         |
|                                                                         |
|                                                                         |
|                                                                         |
|                                                                         |
|                                                                         |
|                                                                         |
|                                                                         |
|                                                                         |
|                                                                         |
|                                                                         |
|                                                                         |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to ensure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/wordinbox dat/1kfnames.txt
==28127== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==28127== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==28127== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==28127== Command: ./bin/wordinbox dat/1kfnames.txt
==28127==
Randomly generated string from list : tor.c

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                                                         |
|                                                                         |
|                                                                         |
|                                                                         |
|                                                                         |
|                                                                         |
|                                                                         |
|                                                                         |
|                                                                         |
|                                                                         |
|                                                                         |
|                                                                         |
|                                                                         |
|                                                                         |
|                                                                         |
|                                                                         |
|                                                                         |
|                                                                         |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
==28127==
==28127== HEAP SUMMARY:
==28127==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28127==   total heap usage: 1,008 allocs, 1,008 frees, 45,566 bytes allocated
==28127==
==28127== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==28127==
==28127== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==28127== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you sir, that is a ton of very helpful information that I will study and learn.